# How to Avoid Running a Formula From a Common Spreadsheet Under Certain Conditions

Tags: excel, if-statement, multiple-resultsets

I am trying to run multiple scenarios in a financial model that all originate from one common set of formulas in a singular sheet. Simultaneously, I would like the results for all non-active scenarios (i.e. if the governing condition is not met) to remain displayed in their respective location instead of a "0".

My goal is to (i) avoid using the "COPY-PASTE" function for each scenario that doesn't meet the active criteria and (ii) leave all the formulas (which draw from the same spreadsheet) in their respective tables (Which summarize each scenario). While a traditional "IF" statement could work, I get hung up on what to put in the "FALSE" category seeing as I do not want to return "0". In the end, I have copy-pasted the results table three different times, and hope to display all results simultaneously without having to copy-paste the numbers.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is too broad. The community cannot develop the whole project for you. Once you have started on a solution, you can ask a specific question if have problem with your code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: To return the current value (instead of zero), the formulas for an inactive scenario would all need to reference themselves - you can't make that work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an IF statement but was to return "blank" value instead of false, you can use a **Null String** (`""`).

For example:

```
=IF(A1=B1,"They Match!","")
```

This will return `They Match!` if cells **A1** and **B1** match, otherwise the cell will remain **blank**.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/ifthenelse-statement) is more information about how to use the `IF` statement in Excel.

Comment: Looks to me like it answers the problem "I get hung up on what to put in the FALSE category seeing as I do not want to return 0."